# Docker engine not enough memory

Tags: docker

I am running docker on Azure VM (Windows server 2019). I am trying to set up airflow using this link - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html. One of the steps include checking available memory for docker. `docker run --rm "debian:buster-slim" bash -c 'numfmt --to iec $(echo $(($(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $(getconf PAGE_SIZE))))'` It requires 4G of memory while I am getting 973M. Any idea how I can increase the docker engine memory. All articles online tell me how I can increase the memory of docker-container.